# Restart Upstart

Tags: upstart, services

I'm in the process of building a job to work in upstart, and any time I have even a typo the entire upstart breaks; not just my job. Is there any way to reload upstart without rebooting?

Comment: Elaborate how it breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `init-checkconf [file.conf]` before you add it to upstart.